# Unable to send mail, i am using gmail for SMTP

Tags: php, email

1. I changed the phpmailer version to 5.2+ ,
2. All magic quote errors got solved.
3. I have allowed less secure app to access my gmail account.
4. How to check SMTP connections error.
   5.($mail-> Send()) function returning false.
5. please guide me.

   ```
   <?php
   require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
   $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
   $mail->Port     = 465;  
   $mail->UserName = "mail@mydomain.com";
   $mail->Password = "password";
   $mail->Host     = "mail.mydomain.com";
   $mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
   $mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
   $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
   $mail->AddAddress("mail@mydomain.com"); 
   $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
   $mail->WordWrap   = 80;
   $mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);
   if(is_array($_FILES) 
   && $_FILES['attachmentFile']['size'] < 2097152 
   && ($_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/pdf" 
   || $_FILES['attachmentFile']['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-  officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") )
   {
   $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachmentFile']['name']);
   }
   else
   {
   echo "<p class='error'>Cannot upload other than PDF & DocX files >  2Mb.</p>";
   exit;
   }
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
     $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
   }
   if(!$captcha){
   echo "<p class='error'>Please check the the captcha form.</p>";
   }
   else 
   {
   if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo "<p class='error'>Problem in uploading file, please try again  later.</p>";
   } 
   else {
   echo "<p class='success'>file received, will get back to you shortly!.</p>";
   }   
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: i have added as guided in that post , but the error still comes as                 1. Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_runtime()     2. Language string failed to load: tls

Comment: according to the question I referenced you have still some options, you can upgrade the phpmailer library to 5.2+ or you can disable the error reporting of deprecated warnings.

Comment: i i upgraded to php mailer 5.2 but error(Class 'SMTP' not found) coming now